# In VS code how to wrap parameters without aligning them?

Tags: visual-studio-code, parameters, indentation

I was used to go to the context menu, and click: wrap every parameter -> indent all parameters.

In recent updates things were mixed up, now in the context menu there is only: wrap every parameter, then the command palette opens up with 3 choices, but each produces the same result: parameters aligned ...BUG!?

What I want is all parameters to be indented on a new line.

[image]

```
    // This is how it is doing it.
    public void Test1(string a,
                      string b,
                      string c)
    {
    }

    // This is how I want it.
    public void Test2(
        string a,
        string b,
        string c)
    {
    }
```

Visual Studio Code

```
Version: 1.85.1
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:47:11.635Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.2.0-39-generic snap
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, I have the C# base language support extension from Microsoft 
ms-dotnettools.csharp v2.14.8, obviously I have a bunch of other extensions but they should be unrelated, actually I assume the feature is builtin. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: I edited the question the responsible extension seems to be ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime.

Comment: probably you should look in the direction of an editorconfig: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/formatting-linting#_how-to-support-editorconfig-with-c-dev-kit

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you use "Indent all parameters" twice, you'll get the result you want. A bit annoying.